# Recursion involving an Array for Wonky Coins

Tags: ruby, arrays, recursion

**Here's the prompt I've been given:**

Catsylvanian money is a strange thing: they have a coin for every
denomination (including zero!). A wonky change machine in
Catsylvania takes any coin of value N and returns 3 new coins,
valued at N/2, N/3 and N/4 (rounding down).

Write a method `wonky_coins(n)` that returns the number of coins you
are left with if you take all non-zero coins and keep feeding them
back into the machine until you are left with only zero-value coins.

Difficulty: 3/5

```
describe "#wonky_coins" do
  it "handles a simple case" do
    wonky_coins(1).should == 3
  end

  it "handles a larger case" do
wonky_coins(5).should == 11
# 11
# => [2, 1, 1]
# => [[1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
# => [[[0, 0, 0], 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
  end

  it "handles being given the zero coin" do
    wonky_coins(0).should == 1
  end

end
```

Maybe it's because of the tests given that involve arrays, but I couldn't get my mind off of them! So my solution so far is as follows:

```
def wonky_coins(n)
    arr = []
    arr << n/2 << n/3 << n/4
    #base case?
    if arr.all?{|coin| coin == 0}
        return arr.flatten.length
        else
        arr.map{|x| wonky_coins(x)}
    end
end

p wonky_coins(5)
```

Except I get [[3,3,3],3,3] as an output if I map it. It's not actually recurring, but even before that, it's giving a strange output that I can't for the life of me understand why the output is this way!

I know it's because I'm using the map method, is it because I'm mutating it while iterating it through wonky_coins again that I'm getting this strange output I can't explain?

I've since looked at the solution and realized that arrays made it needlessly complicated, but I'm still wondering what's going on here??

Comment: It's because you are flattening and getting the length of the array in the base case for the recursive loop. So [0,0,0] -> 3   .... Also would fail the last test wonky_coins(0).should == 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what [Seeing is Believing](https://github.com/JoshCheek/seeing_is_believing) shows as the code runs:

```
def wonky_coins(n)
    arr = []                         # => [], [], [], [], [], [], []
    arr << n/2 << n/3 << n/4         # => [2, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]
    #base case?
    if arr.all?{|coin| coin == 0}    # => false, false, true, true, true, true, true
        return arr.flatten.length    # => 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
        else
        arr.map{|x| wonky_coins(x)}  # => [3, 3, 3], [[3, 3, 3], 3, 3]
    end
end

p wonky_coins(5)  # => [[3, 3, 3], 3, 3]

# >> [[3, 3, 3], 3, 3]
```

Seeing is Believing is a great tool and can help dig out weirdness in code.